# Compute the homology group of $S^{1}\times D^{2}$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

I'm having troubles computing the homology groups of $X=S^{1}\times D^{2}$ where $D^{2}$ is the $2$-disk. Actually I'm not sure what is the best idea here: if we want to apply cellular homology then we (should) have: as $0$-cells $e^{1}_{0}, e^{2}_{0}$, as $1$-cells: $e^{1}_{1}, e^{2}_{1}$ and just one $2$-cell $e_{2}$, but I'm not sure how to proceede now. On the other hand, I tried to find an excisive couple of $X$: $S^{1}$ can be taken as the union of two $1$-cells, say $a_{1}$ and $a_{2}$, in such a way that $A_{1}=a_{1}\times D^{2}$ and $A_{2}=a_{2}\times D^{2}$ is an excisive couple, and both are $A_{1}$ and $A_{2}$ are acyclic. My problem now is, what about the homology of $A_{1}\cap A_{2}$?

Comment: Note that $S^1 \times D^2$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Pedro for the suggestion. The question is not actually hard but it took me off guard, so here is the idea:

since $D^{2}$ is convex, then it is contractible to a single point, so that we can write:
$$D^{2}\simeq\{x_{0}\}$$
Thus:
$$S^{1}\times D^{2}\simeq S^{1}\times\{x_{0}\}\simeq S^{1}$$
which turns into an isomorphism in homology, hence the work is done.